# php-mysql: group by gives error

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have messages table with the following columns:
`id_message_parent,id_user_from,id_user_to,message,read_date,created,status`

I need to select the last message for a user grouped by `id_message_parent` and tried a lot but all query gives white page of death "500 server error" or return the first in order not last like:

```
    {"messages":[{"id_message":"1","id_message_parent":"1","id_user_from":"1","id_user_to":"2","message":"\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627 \u0627\u0646\u0627 \u0645\u0633\u062a\u062e\u062f\u0645 1","read_date":null,"created":"2016-10-17 18:13:39","status":"0"}]}

//while it should be
{"messages":[{"id_message":"2","id_message_parent":"1",.....}]}
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$sql="SELECT *, max(id_message) as max_id FROM `messages` WHERE (`id_user_to`='".$id_user."' OR `id_user_from`='".$id_user."') and `status`='".$status."' GROUP BY `id_message_parent`";

$sql="select * from `messages` where `id_message` in(SELECT *, max(id_message) as max_id FROM `messages` WHERE (`id_user_to`='".$id_user."' OR `id_user_from`='".$id_user."') and `status`='".$status."' GROUP BY `id_message_parent`) x";

$sql="SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id_message` IN (SELECT MAX(id_message) FROM `messages` WHERE (`id_user_to`='".$id_user."' OR `id_user_from`='".$id_user."') and `status`='".$status."') ORDER BY id DESC";

$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `id_user_to`='".$id_user."' OR `id_user_from`='".$id_user."' ORDER BY id DESC) a GROUP BY IF(`id_user_to` = '".$id_user."', `id_user_from`, `id_user_to`)";

$sql="SELECT `id_message`, `id_message_parent`, `id_user_from`, `id_user_to`, `message`, `read_date`, `created`, `status`, GROUP_CONCAT(`id_message`, ',') FROM `messages` GROUP BY `id_message_parent`";
```

and more....
here is the php function

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);    
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){   
$messgs=array();
while ($messgs_info= mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    $info = new Messages();
    $info->id_message=$messgs_info['id_message'];       
    $info->id_message_parent=$messgs_info['id_message_parent'];     
    $info->id_user_from=$messgs_info['id_user_from'];       
    $info->id_user_to=$messgs_info['id_user_to'];   
    $info->message=$messgs_info['message']; 
    $info->read_date=$messgs_info['read_date']; 
    $info->created=$messgs_info['created']; 
    $info->status=$messgs_info['status'];

    array_push($messgs, $info);
}
    echo json_encode(array('messages' => $messgs));
}
```

Comment: what error? plz share, mysql_* is deprecated and closed in php 7, if you are getting white page its something wrong in your code, maybe u having parse error or fatal for extensions. and i also hope this `*$result` typo star right?

Comment: First and foremost thing, don't use mysql. It is deprecated. Use mysqli()

Comment: explain your question & expectation.

Comment: maybe blank page just because of `$info = new Messages();` inside the while loop

Comment: `in(SELECT *, max(id_message) as max_id FROM `messages`` this cant be work like that, you can just use RANGE in `IN ()`

Comment: @devpro yes sorry its typo, but the function works well with othre queries

Comment: i think, your 1 and 3 queries are working fine here right?

Comment: but not returns what is sposed to

Comment: ok 1 and 3 queries are working fine but not returning any result right?

Comment: return the first row like any other random group by query instead of returning the latest row

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not written query properly in $sql variable or might be u have an error in PHP code.

Use below query in phpmyadmin i think it will solve your requirement

```
SELECT msg.* FROM  ( 
    SELECT * FROM message  ORDER BY created DESC)  as msg 
    (msg.`id_user_to`= 2 OR msg.`id_user_from`= 1 ) and msg.`status`= '0'  
    GROUP BY msg.`id_message_parent`";
```

Thanks.

Comment: it say: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(msg.id_user_to= 1 OR msg.id_user_from= 1 ) and msg.status= '0' GROUP BY msg.id_' at line 1

Comment: I guess you messed up with the brackets

Comment: aha there is no  WHERE CLAUSE